# Convert SQL Server query to access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I've got the following SQL Server query and can not for the love of God get this to work in MS Access.

```
select 
   U.voorstellingnummer, U.uitvoeringnummer, U.zaalnaam, S.rijnummer, S.stoelnummer
from 
   Uitvoering as U 
inner join 
   Stoel as S on U.zaalnaam = S.zaalnaam
where 
   U.voorstellingnummer = 4 AND U.uitvoeringnummer = 1 
   AND
   -- (S.rijnummer, S.stoelnummer) not in (select(B.rijnummer, B.stoelnummer)
   ('rij '+ cast(S.rijnummer as varchar(3)) + ' stoel ' + cast(S.stoelnummer as varchar(3))) not in  
         (select('rij '+ cast(B.rijnummer as varchar(3)) + ' stoel ' + cast(B.stoelnummer as varchar(3)))
         from Bezetting as B
         where B.voorstellingnummer = 4 AND B.uitvoeringnummer = 1)
```

I've been add it for a couple of days now but it keeps giving me syntax errors on the first AS.

The query works perfect in SQL Server. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically avoid Access like the plague if I can lol.

However, it looks like your problem might be in the casts. If I remember right, Access will do an implicit conversion from numeric to char. If that's the case, this query should work:

```
select      U.voorstellingnummer, U.uitvoeringnummer, U.zaalnaam, S.rijnummer, S.stoelnummer
from        Uitvoering as U
inner join  Stoel as S
    on      U.zaalnaam = S.zaalnaam
where       U.voorstellingnummer = 4
    AND     U.uitvoeringnummer = 1
    AND     ('rij ' & S.rijnummer & ' stoel '  & S.stoelnummer) not in 
        (
        select      ('rij ' & B.rijnummer & ' stoel ' & B.stoelnummer)
        from        Bezetting as B
        where       B.voorstellingnummer = 4
            AND     B.uitvoeringnummer = 1
        )
```

If the implicit conversions don't work, Cstr() should convert the numbers to strings. If you want only the left 3 characters, you'd probably need to do something like left(cstr(S.rijnummer),3).

Edit: Also, I'm not entirely sure you can use a subquery in the were clause. If not, you might need to make the majority of this a sub query then left join Bezetting to it and use where isnull(Bezetting.rijnummer) - or whatever it is in Access :-)